# Get unique users ids to get list of users with latest conversation

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get users ids with whom i have made latest conversation.

I have not a single idea how to begin with this:

My table structure for messages is like this:

```
id | msg_from_uid | msg_to_uid | msg_text | msg_date
----------------------------------------------------
1  | 8             | 3           | hello   | 2018-03-12 12:00:00
2  | 3             | 8           | hello   | 2018-03-12 12:11:00
3  | 8             | 5           | hello   | 2018-03-12 12:12:00
4  | 5             | 8           | hello   | 2018-03-12 12:13:00
5  | 8             | 7           | hello   | 2018-03-12 12:14:00
6  | 7             | 8           | hello   | 2018-03-12 12:15:00
```

Suppose my user id is 8 then how can i get distinct ids 3,5,7 in lastest conversation order?

I want the unique users ids only. So that i can list them in my left sidebar panel to see with whom i have made latest conversation.

My expected output:

Just ids of users in latest conversation date order:

```
user_id
----
7
5
3
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output?  Do you want to latest conversation involving user 8, or do you want an ordered list of all conversations involving user 8 (in which case you would get 6 records)?

Comment: Hi, i edited my question, i have mentioned what is my expected output.

Comment: If you want user ids to whom message is sent i.e user ids from msg_to_uid column then you can use query from @smit Raval answer like `select msg_to_uid from message where msg_from_uid = 8 order by msg_date DESC `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a least/greatest trick to find the most recent record for each conversation.  This is done in the subquery below labelled `t2`.  Then, we can join your original table to this subquery to obtain the full record.  Finally, to get the counterparty IDs you want, we optionally select the user ID which does *not* match 8 (the source).

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t1.msg_from_uid = 8
         THEN t1.msg_to_uid
         ELSE t1.msg_from_uid END AS uid
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        LEAST(msg_from_uid, msg_to_uid) AS from_id,
        GREATEST(msg_from_uid, msg_to_uid) AS to_id,
        MAX(msg_date) AS max_msg_date
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY
        LEAST(msg_from_uid, msg_to_uid),
        GREATEST(msg_from_uid, msg_to_uid)
) t2
    ON ((t1.msg_from_uid = t2.from_id AND t1.msg_to_uid = t2.to_id) OR
       (t1.msg_from_uid = t2.to_id AND t1.msg_to_uid = t2.from_id)) AND
       t1.msg_date = t2.max_msg_date
WHERE
    t1.msg_from_uid = 8 OR t1.msg_to_uid = 8
ORDER BY
    t1.msg_date DESC;
```

[image]

### Demo

Edit: The join may not actually be necessary if you *only* want the user ID of the counterparty corresponding to the latest conversation.  But the query I gave above may be useful for you in the future, if, for example, you also want to get the text from the latest conversation between each pair of users.

Comment: it worked very well, thanks. But i have to understand it technically step by step, how it works!. Amazing! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hope below solution will help you out.

```
select * from ( SELECT distinct(msg_from_uid), msg_date FROM message where msg_to_uid = 8 UNION SELECT distinct(msg_to_uid), msg_date FROM message where msg_from_uid = 8 ) a group by msg_from_uid order by msg_date desc
```

Output will be

```
msg_from_uid msg_date 
3            2018-03-12 12:15:00
5            2018-03-12 12:13:00
7            2018-03-12 12:11:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest conversation by ordering your query in DESC using msg_date.

```
select * from msg where msg_from_uid = 8 group by msg_to_uid order by msg_date DESC
```

This way you will get unique user_ids and latest messages.